# Can't validate my static option button list

Tags: php, yii

I created a static option list in a page and I want to validate using JavaScript instead of AJAX:

```
<?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'emlevel'); ?>
<?php 
   echo $form->radioButtonList($model,'emlevel',
                  array('L'=>'Low','M'=>'Moderate','X'=>'Low Moderate', 'H'=>'High'),
                  array('separator' => "  " ));
?>
<?php echo $form->error($model,'emlevel'); ?> 





function chk()
{ 
    // first I checked the value for emlevel to verify it get the value or not 
    //but it shows undefined
    alert (document.forms["ConsultationNew"] ["ConsultationNew[enc_type]"].value);
    if (document.forms["ConsultationNew"]["ConsultationNew[emlevel]"].value == null) { 
        alert ('choose one EMlevel'); return false; 
    } 
}
```

I am not able to get value by `document.getelement` ....value. it shows `undefined`

Comment: I am not able to get value by document.getelement ....value.  it shows undefined

Comment: Ajax is not different language or something like this. Can you show us your javascript code too?

Comment: AJAX means "asynchronous javascript and xml". What do you mean with "using javascript instead of AJAX"???

Comment: function chk()
{
    alert (document.forms["ConsultationNew"]["ConsultationNew[enc_type]"].value);
            if (document.forms["ConsultationNew"]["ConsultationNew[emlevel]"].value == null)
        {
            alert ('choose one EMlevel');
            return false;
        }

Comment: I meant 'enableAjaxValidation'=>false, sorry friends I am new to yii

Comment: You should really use jQuery for this. And please, edit the question with the code.

Comment: Thanks friends, I edited the code with my javascript code.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use CActiveForm. Clientside validation is configured as follows:

```
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
'id'=>'login-form',
'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
'enableClientValidation'=>true,
    'clientOptions' => array (
        'validateOnSubmit' => true,
        'validateOnChange' => true,
        'validateOnType' => true,
    ),
)); ?>
```

As you are working in Yii already, I would definitely use CActiveForm for client-side validation (and also for Ajax and server-side validation). It works like a charm. You must have better things to do than to reinvent the wheel in programming validation in Javascript.